# In my android application following bitmap code shows exception

Tags: android

In my android application i get the contact details from contacts for the following code is used i am able to get the name and phone number but bitmap code shows exception

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
String image_uri = "";


image_uri = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID));


if (image_uri != null) {
    System.out.println(Uri.parse(image_uri));
    Log.d("image",image_uri);
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
        this.getContentResolver(),
        Uri.parse(image_uri));
        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+bitmap,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

logcat error:

```
07-31 06:50:15.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1734): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.androidsqlite/com.androidhive.androidsqlite.AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 06:50:15.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-31 06:50:15.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 06:50:15.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at com.androidhive.androidsqlite.AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.onCreate(AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.java:79)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please.

Comment: What is the exception? And how do you know that the bitmap is created?

Comment: @andy256 it shows error on catch (IOException e) {}

Comment: Ok, so what does that tell you?

Comment: if the "imageUri" is wrong that time you will get this exception

Comment: @andy256 it shows null pointer exception.

Comment: @x-code it shows null pointer exception.

Comment: We really need to see the trace, as @silverback requested.

Comment: @silverback I have learned something today!